# Multithread image download with cURL, PHP

Tags: php, image, curl, download

I'm trying to use cURL to download images from an URL with multiple connections to speed up the process.

Here's my code:

```
function multiRequest($data, $options = array()) {

// array of curl handles
$curly = array();
// data to be returned
$result = array();

// multi handle
$mh = curl_multi_init();

// loop through $data and create curl handles
// then add them to the multi-handle
foreach ($data as $id => $d) {

    $path = 'image_'.$id.'.png';
    if(file_exists($path)) { unlink($path); }
    $fp = fopen($path, 'x');

    $url = $d;
    $curly[$id] = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

    fclose($fp);

    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $curly[$id]);
}

// execute the handles
$running = null;
do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
} while($running > 0);


// get content and remove handles
foreach($curly as $id => $c) {
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $c);
}

// all done
curl_multi_close($mh);
}
```

And executing:

```
$data = array(
    'http://example.com/img1.png',
    'http://example.com/img2.png',
    'http://example.com/img3.png'
);

$r = multiRequest($data);
```

So it's not really working. It creates the 3 files, but with zero bytes (empty), and giving me the following error (3 times) and it's printing some kind of content of the original .PNGs:

```
Warning: curl_multi_exec(): CURLOPT_FILE resource has gone away, resetting to default in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test.php on line 34
```

So please, could you let me know how to work it out?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is creating a file handle then closing it before the end of the loop. This is going to result in curl not having any file to write to. Try something like this:

```
//$fp = fopen($path, 'x'); Remove

$url = $d;
$curly[$id] = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_FILE, fopen($path, 'x'));

//fclose($fp); Remove
```

Comment: and where to open the file & write & close?

Comment: Its opened as part of the setopt call. Generally resources are closed at the end of a script, but if you need to close it, you could assign the resources to an array and close them after curl is done.

Comment: helped thanks :) And I could do the `fclose` next to `curl_multi_remove_handle`! Thanks again!